# Remove Required field on Customer Create Account

Tags: magento, account, required-field

We have a problem with our create a account page. Even when all field are filled in we still get a message: "****" is a required field. The page where we get this error is:

http://oolabooshop.com/customer/account/create/

Does anyone know a solution or a way to remove this requirement.

Comment: Is there any attribute created name "****" in admin customer?

Comment: do you have a required customer attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a Customer attribute "Your Salon" in the Magento admin which is a required attribute and it is configured to be used in "Customer Account Edit" form via attribute's frontend properties.

Please navigate to `Customer >> Attribute >> Manage Customer Attributes`

and click on the mentioned attribute and cross-check its properties to meet your requirement.

Comment: I can't find this in the backend of the Magento admin. Could give a indication where i can find this?

Comment: It seems you are having Community version, it is available inside admin in Enterprise version. So, you have to ask your developer to look into the database.

Comment: BTW..You can look remove the mandatory mark by updating the table "eav_attribute" and can remove the attribute from Customer edit for by updating the table "customer_form_attribute" for that attribute.. But as this DB related task make sure to take backup and ask the developer to do it keeping in mind that the site is live.

Comment: Thanks i've download a extension that addes these functions tot the Community Version. You can find the extension here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/manage-customer-attributes.html

Comment: Great, I was aware of that extn but just realized that its free